# Why is an empty file created whenever i open an sqlite connection in my wpf app?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am using sqlite database for my wpf application, i put it inside the release folder, however whenever i open my app and it tries to connect to the database, it will copy the database and create a FILE type, so for example my database is called InventoryDB and its a type of SQLite database, if i open my program, a file called InventoryDB of type FILE will be generated within the same folder ,and my program will crash because it will try to connect to the InventoryDB of type file with no data in it instead of the actual InventoryDB of type SQLite database that contains all the data

```
  SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=InventoryDB");
   void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        conn.Open();
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("insert into loginfo (info) values (1)", conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to put in the extension to the file.
Something like this:

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=InventoryDB.db");
```